# GDI+ DrawString generic exception when drawing a string with a length over 65536?

Tags: c#, gdi+

Here is some C# code written in linqpad to reproduce the issue.

```
var font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 8);
using (var g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    //65536 characters is fine
    g.DrawString("a".PadLeft(65535, 'a'), font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 1, 1));
    //65537 characters causes an error.
    g.DrawString("a".PadLeft(65536, 'a'), font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 1, 1));
    //65537 characters is however fine if the width is over 600581
    g.DrawString("a".PadLeft(65536, 'a'), font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, new System.Drawing.RectangleF(0, 0, 600582, 1));
}
```

Anyone know the exact relationship between the string's length and the layout rectangle's width? The number 600581 seems very arbitrary. Although 65536 makes more sense as that is 0x10000.

Comment: Most "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exceptions are because the program can't write to a file because of permissions.  Maybe the numbers you are experimenting with are triggering file caching.

Comment: Dies at 32001 for me on Win8.  Avoid pushing GDI+ to the edge, it will byte you.  You should be using TextRenderer here.

Comment: I don't think so because I can pass a string that's 1 million in length if the layout width is over an arbitrary number.

Comment: @SteveWellens I don't see a relation between "generic error" and files. Why do you think so?

Comment: @usr That is because most gdi+ exceptions are "generic error". One of the more common ones to hit is trying to save a GDI+ image to a file that you don't have permissions to write. Although I think this error has nothing to do with permissions.

Comment: @usr - Ditto what Will said.  I'm just suggesting that STATISTICALLY, most GDI+ generic errors are permission related.  And given the fact that you are messing with large numbers that are close to a 'magic' memory boundary number...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone know the exact relationship between the string's length and the
>   layout rectangle's width? The number 600581 seems very arbitrary.

The number 600581 is indeed arbitrary and in this case it reflects the fonts char widths (or the typeface's glyphs).

Take for example `600581 / 65536` which gives an average char-width of 9.16 pixels per char which is reasonable for a fairly squared font such as Arial when you include spacing. GDI+ also adds padding to the text's bounding box in addition to this.

If you try a wider (or a narrower font, but you wouldn't notice unless reducing the number) as well as different letter combinations you should get different results. Try a mono-spaced font and you should be able to predict pretty accurately the needed boundaries (don't forget the padding).

If you really need to print long strings try to buffer the printing, however GDI+ isn't your best friend in these cases. Try the `TextRenderer` class (a GDI wrapper) as already suggested:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.aspx